# Hide an element when clicking anywhere outside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to have an element be hidden when you click anywhere outside of it.

It is a drop down that appears when you click on the CART link in the top left.  The problem I seem to be facing is two fold.

1) When you click on anything in that button other then just CART, it's showing and then hiding the .cart-dropdown DIV.  I am guessing it's because I'm not targeting the correct classes in this piece of code:

```
$(document).click (function (e) {
  if (e.target != $('.cart-dropdown')[0] && e.target != $('.cart-nav-item')[0] && e.target != $('.cart-full')[0]) {
    $('.cart-dropdown').hide();
  }
});
```

2) The `.cart-dropdown` DIV also closes when you click within it, which is what I want to avoid.  Again this must relate to an error in my syntax / logic in the above piece of code.

Can someone please point me in the correct direction?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you click outside the `document`?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the way you're checking the classes and elements, it will work.  See this fiddle for a working example, using the code below:

https://jsfiddle.net/freginold/kv44k1uu/

HTML:

```
<div>
  A div
</div>
<br>
<div id='cart' class='cart-dropdown'>
  Cart
</div>
<br>
<div>
 Another Div
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).click (function (e) {
//alert($(e.target).hasClass("cart-dropdown"));
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('cart-dropdown') && !$(e.target).hasClass('cart-nav-item') && !$(e.target).hasClass('cart-full')) {
    $('.cart-dropdown').hide();
  }
});
```

You were on the right track; you just had to target the element through jQuery like @Our_Benefactors said, and then change the way you checked the element's class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
e.target
```

to

```
$(e.target)
```

to treat it as a jquery object.

Comment: I did that, but I think it's because I'm still not using the correct class names in my IF statement to stop .cart-dropdown from being hidden directly after clicking on CART.  Is there a way to see what the class name is of the element being clicked on?

Comment: I fixed this by giving every element that I didn't want it to close on the same ID.  Probably not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: @user1110562 If you're using jQuery, you can use `.hasClass()` to see if it's the class you want (or don't want).  More info on that method [here](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Comment: @user1110562 I would strongly recommend not giving multiple elements the same ID.  You can see a working example of how to make it work using classes in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122584/hide-an-element-when-clicking-anywhere-outside-it/43124602#43124602).